# Capture error message in Web Application using QTP

Tags: automation, qtp

I wanna capture the error message from the web based application during the run-time of QTP if  server couldn't able to process the request which was hardcoded.

Example: If i'm trying run for sign-up page were i hardcoded all the fields but in the website they asking for minimum of 8 character for the field password but i hardcoded only 6 character.

I'm facing an error while running QTP and that web application shows additional "Pop-up" page. I wanna capture that message in that pop-up window and need to store string for future purpose.

Pls help me

Answer (score 0):

You can typically use an [**Output Value**](http://www.qtpworld.com/index.php?cid=70) to capture strings from elements in the application. How to do this exactly depends on the way your application displays the error message, you will have to give some more details if you want a more specific answer.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I have completed the script and will trigged the QTP with the help of VBScript and i will share how my application works.

If the user try to log in by using sign-up page where all the fields are mandatory and if the user forget to give the specified field which has a constraint of 8 character need to be entered.  An pop-up will be display (Javascript we can have an option 
called ALERT). In that pop-up i wanna capture the error message while 
automation takes place and that message have to store in the variable for my
future purpose

Answer (score 0):

Use the QTP Recovery Scenario feature and setup trigger for a popup having a specific window title.